# 1995 BMW 325i stalls

Tags: stall, 325i

My 1995 BMW stalls intermittently when stopped in traffic.

First it's like it loses electrical power then engine dies. It starts back up immediately and shows no codes at the mechanic shop.

Already replaced the idle air control valve, flushed fuel system, smoke test, fuel filter... still stalls.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is the condition of the intake boot (the "rubber" intake hose)? The idle air control valve is the normal culprit but torn intake hoses are very common on that particular car.

Answer (score 3):

Thank goodness for my mechanics that kept on researching until they figured it out. They didn't keep replacing parts guessing at what was wrong.  But they kept on it.   They called me one day and said they thought they had the answer and they did!  Turns out it was a faulty TCC Lock UP Solenoid....Now it runs like a charm with no stalling!

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the answer, sounds like you have a great mechanic!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a massive short somewhere, makes sense the engine would die when you lose power because what’s gonna power the injectors and sparks!!
What are the events leading up to the short like? There could be something melted somewhere for instance and shorting itself out on the frame of the car